# Cannot find name 'TaskData'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My project was acting weird and tried to refresh the node modules installation. After remove node modules directory  and reinstall through npm install I get the next error.

I tried to upgrade to Angular 10 and try to use node 13 and node 14 but the error seems to persist.

```
ERROR in node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:42:101 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TaskData'.

42 export declare function scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone(source: string, callback: Function, data?: TaskData, customSchedule?: (task: Task) => void, customCancel?: (task: Task) => void): MacroTask;
                                                                                                       ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:42:135 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Task'.

42 export declare function scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone(source: string, callback: Function, data?: TaskData, customSchedule?: (task: Task) => void, customCancel?: (task: Task) => void): MacroTask;
                                                                                                                                         ~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:42:172 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Task'.

42 export declare function scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone(source: string, callback: Function, data?: TaskData, customSchedule?: (task: Task) => void, customCancel?: (task: Task) => void): MacroTask;
                                                                                                                                                                              ~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:42:188 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MacroTask'.

42 export declare function scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone(source: string, callback: Function, data?: TaskData, customSchedule?: (task: Task) => void, customCancel?: (task: Task) => void): MacroTask;
                                                                                                                                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:57:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TaskData'.

57 export interface MacroTaskMeta extends TaskData {
                                          ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/utils.d.ts:64:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TaskData'.

64 export interface MicroTaskMeta extends TaskData {
                                          ~~~~~~~~
```

These are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "thrift": "git+https://github.com/apache/thrift.git",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "stream": "^0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.5",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "^5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^3.1.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
```

Comment: Its connected with angular version. You should upgrade your angular version or look at this comment: https://github.com/PatrickJS/starter/issues/452#issuecomment-201996986

Comment: This is connected to angular 2 and  I am using angular  10.0.1 (The latest). I had this issue with angular 9 so I upgraded it an it did not fixed the error . I tried the comment solution just in case  is a reoccurring bug, but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My IDE had added a unwanted import:

```
import { copySymbolProperties } from 'zone.js/lib/common/utils';
```

Comment: Different import but still from zone.js. Pesky IDE trying to be helpful!